# Warning when I am calling too much per month

Tags: android, phone

My phone plan is a great deal as long as I make fewer than 300 minutes of calls per month but is very expensive if I make more. I find that once every few months I inadvertently go over and get a huge bill.

Can anyone recommend an app for  my android phone that will warn me if I'm going over my minutes allowance? Ideally it would not require me to check it regularly but would pop up an alarm of some sort.

Comment: Have you looked in the app store?

Comment: @rrirower  Yes of course. Maybe I am looking using the wrong search terms.

Comment: I don't remember about "pop-ups", but some of the [Call Stats](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_statistics#group_94) apps (link goes to my list/collection of such) at least have widgets showing how much is left (I've used [DroidStats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nitro.phonestats) for quite a while which has that, but seems no longer to be updated).

Answer (score 2):

[Control Your Calls](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=creativemad.controlyourcalls&hl=en):

> If you have a flat rate of calls, Control Your Calls is your application. It will be your best friend to save on mobile fee. It will help you not to exceed the limits of your rate, avoiding shocks when you receive the invoice.

Alternatively, [My Call Duration](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aaarju.calls&hl=en):

> If you have single plain plan of month like 300 call free then you can
>   a) go to "= Settings(Theme,plan etc.)" s page and enable your plan.
>   b) set your call quota i.e. 300 and
>   c) set your plan pulse rate like per minute or per second.
>   d)Then go to main screen (=Home), you will see one progress bar with text like 20/300.
>   e) now select 'today' drop down and select 'Day of Month' option and type your plan date. That's it. You will see your monthly data.

There's even some open-source app, [Call Meter NG](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.ub0r.de.android.callMeterNG):

> Call Meter lets you keep an eye on your mobile plans.
>   It shows statistics of your calls/sms/txt/data traffic and lets you set limits for each of these plans.
>   Call Meter supports a huge amount of billing modes to let you adapt it's behaviour to your operators billing.